# UIButtons in Custom UIView not responding (again)

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uibutton

I have a custom UIView with some buttons as subviews. I read a lot of threads about my problem but the solutions which were posted didn't work for me.

If I set the frame of one of the buttons to some coordinates outside of my UIView, the button works. When I set the frame of one of the buttons to some coordinates where the custom UIView and the button are overlapping, the button responds only in the area where they are not overlapping.

This is my Code:

**I initialize the custom UIView in the viewDidLoad method:**

```
[super viewDidLoad];

DDButtonBar *ddButtonBar =  _ddButtonBar;

[ddButtonBar showButton1:TRUE];
[ddButtonBar showButton2:TRUE];
[ddButtonBar showButton3:TRUE];
[ddButtonBar showButton4:TRUE];
[ddButtonBar showBackButton:TRUE];
[ddButtonBar showSettingsButton:TRUE];

[ddButtonBar setButtonTitle1:@"1"];
[ddButtonBar setButtonTitle2:@"2"];
[ddButtonBar setButtonTitle3:@"3"];
[ddButtonBar setButtonTitle4:@"4"];
```

**This is my init method of the UIView:**

```
 - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame

self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {

    // Standardinitialisierung
    _drawButton1 = TRUE;
    _drawButton2 = TRUE;
    _drawButton3 = TRUE;
    _drawButton4 = TRUE;
    _drawBackButton = TRUE;
    _drawSettingsButton = TRUE;

    _buttonTitle1 = @"1";
    _buttonTitle2 = @"2";
    _buttonTitle3 = @"3";
    _buttonTitle4 = @"4";

    [self layoutSubviews];


}
return self;
```

}

**I'm drawing my buttons like that**

```
 UIButton *button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button1 addTarget:self
            action:@selector(aMethod:)
  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button1 setTitle:_buttonTitle1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];

button1.frame = CGRectMake(rechtsverschiebung, height, buttonWidth, height);

[button1 setBackgroundImage:_buttonBackground forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button1 setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:255.0 green:255.0 blue:255 alpha:1.0] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
[button1 setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:247.0 green:165.0 blue:32 alpha:1.0] forState: UIControlStateHighlighted];

[self addSubview:button1];
```

Comment: [self.view bringSubviewtofront:<urbutton>]; try this

Comment: I tried that already, I will post what I exactly did. I tried this in my viewDidLoad     [self.view bringSubviewToFront:_ddButtonBar];
and this in my custom UIView     [self bringSubviewToFront:button1];
I can not use [self.view ...] in my custom UIView.

Comment: Best option is to give diffrent color to all view see which view is above your button or your button rect might be going outside the rect of view on which it is added

Answer (score 0):

Check the y position of the next button.In your code you setting the same y position for all button.

Comment: My UI looks like that, so I think the positions should be OK and they don't overlap. http://imageshack.us/a/img600/4877/iossimulatorbildschirmf.png

Comment: I Found the problem. My Buttons were not positioned in the actual UIView area, the were pushed down some pixels. Thank you :)